# Loadrunner Winsock protocol lrs_get_static_buffer() function call results in memory violation

Tags: c, memory, winsock, access-violation, loadrunner

Good day!

I'm experiencing problems running my Vugen Winsock script on remote Load Generator (Performance Center Host) with HP ALM Performance Center.

On remote Load Generator it fails with run time error on first [lrs_get_static_buffer()](https://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#winsocket/lrFr_lrs_get_static_buffer.htm?Highlight=lrs_get_static_buffer) call.

Error from VUser log:

```
Action.c(138):  lrs_get_static_buffer(socket0, buf0, 0, -1, null)
Action.c(138): Error: С interpreter run time error: Action.c (138): Error -- memory violation : Exception ACCESS_VIOLATION received.
```

Script is working fine when it is started with VuGen on local machine.

Script is working fine on remote Load Generator while script is sending unmodified data from recording (with all replace_data() function calls commented).

Static buffer "buf0" which i'm trying to get is holding only 61 bytes.

```
send buf0 61

"\n"

"\x00"

...

"R\b"


recv buf1 32
...
```

"data.ws" file content is intact from recording phase.

Code:

```
char * buffer;


...


int replace_data (char * buffer_desc)

{

long size;

...

buffer = lrs_get_static_buffer("socket0", buffer_desc, 0, -1, NULL); // here is the problem

size = lrs_get_user_buffer_size("socket0");

...

// replacing some bytes

...

lrs_set_send_buffer("socket0", buffer, size);

}


Action()

{

int rc;
buffer = (char *) malloc (4096 * sizeof(char));

...

rc = lrs_create_socket("socket0", "TCP", "RemoteHost={hostname}:{port}", LrsLastArg);

...

replace_data("buf0");

rc = lrs_length_send("socket0", "buf0", 0, LrsLastArg);

...

rc = lrs_close_socket("socket0");

}
```

Please help me with this.

I'm [already asked](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-Practitioners-Forum/Winsock-lrs-get-static-buffer-error-memory-violation/td-p/1610057) this question on HPE Loadrunner Practitioners Forum but still don't get an answer.

Comment: I cannot see your post on the forum. You placed a link to the forum main page. If you post the link to the actual question I will ask someone to take a look at it.

Comment: https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-Practitioners-Forum/Winsock-lrs-get-static-buffer-error-memory-violation/td-p/1610057